# How To Replace Pandas Column NaN Values with Empty List Values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a `json` string of records where the "schema" for each record is not consistent (e.g. each record does not have the full set of "columns"):

```
s = """[{"a": 3, "b":[]}, {"a": 4, "b": [4]}, {"a": 5}]"""
```

A pandas `DataFrame` can be constructed from this string:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

json_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(json.loads(s))
```

Which results in

```
   a    b
0  3   []
1  4  [4]
2  5  NaN
```

**How can all `NaN` instances of a pandas `Series` column be filled with empty `list` values?**  The expected resulting DataFrame would be:

```
   a    b
0  3   []
1  4  [4]
2  5   []
```

I have tried the following; none of which worked:

```
json_df[json_df.b.isna()] = [[]]*json_df[json_df.b.isna()].shape[0]

from itertools import repeat
json_df[json_df.b.isna()] = repeat([], json_df[json_df.b.isna()].shape[0])

import numpy as np
json_df[json_df.b.isna()] = np.repeat([], json_df[json_df.b.isna()].shape[0])
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first find the nan and replace by the same shape of data

```
json_df.loc[json_df.b.isnull(), 'b'] = json_df.loc[json_df.b.isnull(), 'b'].apply(lambda x: [])


    a   b
0   3   []
1   4   [4]
2   4   []
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Comment: simplemente estas asignando al valor de esa fila [] con apply de forma innecesaria